# Android Can't get two virtual joysticks to move independently and at the same time

Tags: android, joystick

```
   @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        float r = 70;
        float centerLx = (float) (screenWidth*.3425);
        float centerLy = (float) (screenHeight*.4958);
        float centerRx = (float) (screenWidth*.6538);
        float centerRy = (float) (screenHeight*.4917);
        float dx = 0;
        float dy = 0;
        float theta;
        float c;

        int action = event.getAction(); 
        int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK; 
        int pid = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
        int fingerid = event.getPointerId(pid);
        int x = (int) event.getX(pid);
        int y = (int) event.getY(pid);




            c = FloatMath.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
            theta = (float) Math.atan(Math.abs(dy/dx));


            switch (actionCode) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

                //if touching down on left stick, set leftstick ID to this fingerid.                                                             
                if(x < screenWidth/2 && c<r*.8) {
                    lsId = fingerid;
                                    dx = x-centerLx;
                        dy = y-centerLy;
                    touchingLs = true;
                }
                else if(x > screenWidth/2 && c<r*.8) {
                    rsId = fingerid;
                                    dx = x-centerRx;
                                    dy = y-centerRy;
                    touchingRs = true;
                }



                    break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:


            if (touchingLs && fingerid == lsId) { 
                dx = x - centerLx;
                dy = y - centerLy;
            }else if (touchingRs && fingerid == rsId) { 
                dx = x - centerRx;
                dy = y - centerRy;
            }


                c = FloatMath.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
                theta = (float) Math.atan(Math.abs(dy/dx));


                //if touching outside left radius and moving left stick
                if(c >= r && touchingLs && fingerid == lsId) {
                    if(dx>0 && dy<0) { //top right quadrant
                        lsX = r * FloatMath.cos(theta);
                        lsY = -(r * FloatMath.sin(theta));
                        Log.i("message", "top right");
                    }

                    if(dx<0 && dy<0) { //top left quadrant
                        lsX = -(r * FloatMath.cos(theta));
                        lsY = -(r * FloatMath.sin(theta));
                        Log.i("message", "top left");
                    }

                    if(dx<0 && dy>0) { //bottom left quadrant
                        lsX = -(r * FloatMath.cos(theta));
                        lsY = r * FloatMath.sin(theta);
                        Log.i("message", "bottom left");
                    }


                    else if(dx > 0 && dy > 0){ //bottom right quadrant
                        lsX = r * FloatMath.cos(theta);
                        lsY = r * FloatMath.sin(theta);
                        Log.i("message", "bottom right");
                    }


                }
                if(c >= r && touchingRs && fingerid == rsId) {
                    if(dx>0 && dy<0) { //top right quadrant
                        rsX = r * FloatMath.cos(theta);
                        rsY = -(r * FloatMath.sin(theta));
                        Log.i("message", "top right");
                    }
                    if(dx<0 && dy<0) { //top left quadrant
                        rsX = -(r * FloatMath.cos(theta));
                        rsY = -(r * FloatMath.sin(theta));
                        Log.i("message", "top left");
                    }
                    if(dx<0 && dy>0) { //bottom left quadrant
                        rsX = -(r * FloatMath.cos(theta));
                        rsY = r * FloatMath.sin(theta);
                        Log.i("message", "bottom left");
                    }
                    else if(dx > 0 && dy > 0) {
                        rsX = r * FloatMath.cos(theta);
                        rsY = r * FloatMath.sin(theta);
                        Log.i("message", "bottom right");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if(c < r && touchingLs && fingerid == lsId) {
                        lsX = dx;
                        lsY = dy;
                    }
                    if(c < r && touchingRs && fingerid == rsId){
                        rsX = dx;
                        rsY = dy;
                    }

                } 

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

            if (fingerid == lsId) { 
                lsId = -1;
                lsX = 0;
                lsY = 0;
                touchingLs = false;
            } else if (fingerid == rsId) { 
                rsId = -1;
                rsX = 0;
                rsY = 0;
                touchingRs = false;
            }


                break;
            }



        return true;
    }
```

There's a left joystick and a right joystick. Right now only one will move at a time. If someone could set me on the right track I would be incredibly grateful cause I've been having nightmares about this problem.

Comment: It's a wall of code that very few people are going to decode :) But try: http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html

It talks about masked actions.

Comment: I'm not very experienced so I kinda just assume people who are good at this stuff read code like the guy from the matrix reads the scrolling green code. Thanks though

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging your code for you.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a direct problem with your code, but here are a few pointers on dealing with Android Multi-touch Input

- Make sure you **include the uses-feature in your AndroidManifest.xml for multitouch**. I am not sure if it is just a cautionary setting to disable your app on devices that don't support it, or if it actually does activate it on your app:

`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" />`

- You should probably **handle the `ACTION_XXX` & `ACTION_POINTER_XXX` a bit differently from each other**. The first is given when the primary finger (first) finger touches the screen or last one leaves respectively. The second one is used whenever any extra (called `Non-Primary` by the SDK) finger touches down or up.
- Note that not all pointer touch downs would be reported. To overcome that, **whenever a `ACTION_MOVE` event would fire, first check if that `pointerID` is already existent**, if not, then create it as if it had just landed there
- Lastly, most device screens are VERY sensitive, to the point where there is motion reported, when the user would not even notice moving finger at all (or even intended to). To overcome this, **include a `Movement Threshold` at every movement event, and only consider the finger moved if it exceeds the threshold**

I hope these pointers at least give you a starting point on where to look further into solving your problem